# Regex to match class name without fully qualified name

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I'm doing a code generator in Java and I'm struggling with this regex.

**I need to** find every `classname` in the `String sourceCode` and replace them with `fullyQualifiedClassName`.

With the following code...

```
String regex = "(?<=(^|\\n| |\\.))" + className + "(?=(<|\\.|\\())";
val = val.replaceAll(regex, fullyQualifiedClassName);
```

... I can match every `classname` that:

- starts with `begin of line`, `line break`, `space`, or `.` (dot for static inner classes)
- and ends with `<`(generic), `.`(static method call or static inner class) or `(`(new instance)

The problem is that if `sourceCode` already contains a fully qualified class name, it will replace again. For example: `sourceCode` contains `java.util.Random` and this will be replaced by `java.util.java.util.Random`

I'm trying to find a way to add to the first part of the regex a rule that says:

- and does not contain `fullyQualifiedClassName.replace(className, "")`

any help will be great appreciated.

**edit:** an example,

it's a silly example, but it shows what is missing.

```
Random r = new java.util.Random();
```

in the above code, the first `Random` should be replaced when I call `replaceAll` and the second `Random` should not be matched.

I have in the processor code easily available the variables

```
String className = "Random";
String fullyQualifiedClassName = "java.util.Random";
String package = fullyQualifiedClassName.replace(className, "");
```

Comment: pls provide a reproducable example.. You should use a negative lookbehind assertion.

Comment: @AvinashRaj please look at the edit. I've added an example. I was looking into negative lookbehind, but struggling to make it work.

Comment: I'd try to replace the lookbehind with `"(?<!\\.)\\b"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew any reason for that?

Comment: If your name is fully qualified, it is preceded with a `.`, isn't it? Try [`(?<!\\.)\\bRandom(?=\\b|[<.(])`](https://regex101.com/r/jT3aO1/1). Or `(?<=^|\\s)(?<!\\.)Random\\b(?=[<.(])`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes. But there're other conditions. preceded by a dot can also be a static inner class, and in that case I want to match.

Comment: @Budius but wouldn't you want to the inner classes of the provided class? in that case, the inner class name (and the associated dot) would follow the provided class name rather than preceed it

Comment: My second regex suggestion is not correct, I meant to suggest [`(?<=^|\s)(?<!\.)Random(?=\b|[<.(])`](https://regex101.com/r/jT3aO1/2).  Or even [`(?<=^|\\s)(?<!\\.)Random\\b`](https://regex101.com/r/jT3aO1/3) should work. If not, please provide more test cases.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that worked fine. I guess I was trying to replace the inner class itself, but it can also be excluded. I've just tested here in the live code with all possible weird examples and it's all fine. Do you care to write it as an answer?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've ended up using: `String regex = "(?<=^|\\s)(?<!\\.)" + className + "(?=\\b|[<.(])";`

Comment: Sorry, was busy with the R code :) Yes, I will write the answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that fully qualified names should not be preceded with `.`. So, you need to use a negative lookbehind `(?<!\.)`. Also, the `\n` and   are whitespaces, you may shrink those parts to just `\s`. In the lookahead, you also match single characters with an alternation group, while a character class is more appropriate for this task.

So, use

```
String regex = "(?<=^|\\s)(?<!\\.)" + className + "(?=\\b|[<.(])";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jT3aO1/2)

**Explanation**"

- `(?<=^|\\s)` - a positive lookbehind requiring the start of string or a whitespace to be right before the current position in the string
- `(?<!\\.)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if `.` is right before the current position
- *className* - the variable for the class (note that in this case you do not have to use `Pattern.quote` as it should only consist of "word" characters)
- `(?=\\b|[<.(])` - a positive lookahead that requires a word boundary or a `<` or `.` or `(` to be right after the class name.